# How do I make git merge's default be --no-ff --no-commit?

Tags: git, merge

Company policy is to use `--no-ff` for merge commits. I personally like to adjust merge log messages so I use `--no-commit`. Plus I like to actually compile and test before I let the commit go.

How do I make `--no-ff` and `--no-commit` the default for me for all branches?

(and I've learned in the years since asking this, I almost always am happy with the commit, so it is simpler to allow it to commit by default and so long as I amend or otherwise fix things up before doing a push things are all good...)

Comment: older related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Put this in $HOME/.gitconfig:

```
[merge]
    ff = no
    commit = no
```

You can use git-config to do this:

```
  git config --global merge.commit no
  git config --global merge.ff no
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? It does not for me, I had to use either `branch.master.mergeoptions="--no-ff"`, or `merge.ff="no"` (see answer below)

Comment: @gaizka  Indeed, in 1.7.2 and in 1.7.7.2 it does not work.  I'll try to get some time later to check older versions.

Comment: @Stripes using the git config command, it puts it in [merge], not [core]

Comment: This does not work for me. Maybe git does not even has merge.commit option, see [git-merge-with-no-commit-as-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615355/git-merge-with-no-commit-as-default)

Comment: No, [there has never been a merge.commit config variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70617448/1824182), it's just that `git config` will allow the user to set any random text as a variable name (on the off chance some other software tool uses it).

Comment: Is this still up-to-date ? It doesn't work for me. I can find no mention of a similar configuration variable in more recent versions of Git.

Comment: @Charles, as the previous comments pointed out, `merge.commit` doesn't do anything, but see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge/#Documentation/git-merge.txt-mergeff) for `merge.ff`

Answer (score 67):

To make `--no-ff --no-commit` the default merge behavior, set the options to `no` using:

```
git config --global merge.ff no
git config --global merge.commit no
```

However, the problem with this is that `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`. So whenever you pull from the remote server, you'd be creating an ugly merge commit when a simple fast-forward would be warranted. To solve this, set `pull.ff` to `yes`:

```
git config --global pull.ff yes
```

Comment: While this is true when using mergeoptions, it should be noted that if you're using `merge.ff` instead then it doesn't do this - it only affects explicit merges, while pulls still do the desired fast forward.

Comment: When I use `merge.ff = no`, `git pull` creates merge commits.

Comment: to solve this you should use `git pull --rebase` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) or configure `branch.autosetuprebase` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html)

Comment: or use `pull.ff = yes`

Comment: Is this still up-to-date ? It doesn't work for me. I can find no mention of a similar configuration variable in more recent versions of Git.

Comment: @Charles it is. I would even recommend `pull.ff = only` instead of `yes` so instead of trying to perform a merge the pull will just fail.

Answer (score 22):

As of version 1.7.6 of git, you should use

```
git config [--global] merge.ff no
```

to "force" using `--no-ff` in every merge.

Default behaviour is

```
git config [--global] merge.ff yes
```

And with

```
git config [--global] merge.ff only
```

it will refuse non-fast-forward merges

Comment: Is this still up-to-date ? It doesn't work for me. I can find no mention of a similar configuration variable in more recent versions of Git.

Answer (score 15):

According to [manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), you should use

```
$ git config [--global] merge.ff false
```

to set no-fast-forward option by default for all branches with git-config utility.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date ? It doesn't work for me. I can find no mention of a similar configuration variable in more recent versions of Git.