# Not possible to fast-forward even with no changes

Tags: git

I ended up in a weird git state. I want to pull from server, only fast forwards.

However, even when there were no changes, git keeps telling me "not possible fast-forward".

```
$ git pull -v --ff-only
From github.com:username/repo
 = [up to date]      branch    -> origin/branch
 = [up to date]      branch2    -> origin/branch2
 = [up to date]      branch3    -> origin/branch3
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

How do I tell git to tell me more information about this "non-possibility" of fast-forward? I canot be more verbose...

Comment: "up to date" here means that your `refs/remotes/origin/master` is up to date with the `master` branch on the server.  It does not mean your local branch (`refs/heads/master`) is up to date with the remote.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happens when (a) you committed something on that branch earlier, or (b) the history on the remote server changed in a non-standard way (this shouldn't normally happen but repository owners sometimes don't play by the rules).

For the following I'm assuming you're on `foo` and the upstream branch is `origin/foo`.

- Use `git log ..origin/foo` to see what commits are new on the remote side.
- Use `git log origin/foo..` to see what commits exist on your side that don't exist on the remote side (this will show you any commits that are preventing fast-forwarding).
- If you conclude that those commits are not needed or already present in a different form on the remote side, `git reset --hard origin/foo` to force your branch to become equal to the remote one (this will destroy all uncommitted changes and any commits not contained in `remote/foo` will become unreachable).

Comment: Hm. Now it seems like one of the branches was force pushed while I have another copy. However I can just `reset --hard` and call it a day, right.

Comment: Thanks and this is a very clearly documented tutorial. `git log` does the checking part and `git reset` does the fix. This happened to me as I unusually changed a file on github webpage (due to local/remote variations) which is exactly something done in a --non-standard way--

Comment: You have saved my life...(Y)

Answer (score 40):

Your commits on your 'develop' branch do not match the commits on your 'origin' branch. Do this:

```
git pull origin develop --rebase
```

Answer (score 0):

**A workaround.**

I'm **using Xcode via Beanstalk** to Push/Pull to the Git. Here’s how I worked around this problem.

```
 The problem: 
 During the Xcode 7 to 8 upgrade, code added by my constituents was not Pulled
 into my Xcode, thus causing a Not Possible to Fast Forward error.
```

**The workaround:** My constituents overseas duplicated the Master Branch to a new branch called NEW Branch, then pushed the code.  I then pulled.

*We’re up and running.*

I then went to our account in Beanstalkapp.com and changed my base branch from Master to NEW.

My last move would be to merge the Master into the NEW Branch, but I probably will do a Compare within Beanstalk, then pick out the changes I had made that have not been put into the code in the Git server, then add them manually within the NEW Branch.

Hope that helps.