# git pull: Not possible to fast-forward,

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

could you please help me to solve my issue? Error occurs when I try to pull from "dev" branch.
I browsed the solution and it says that I need to "rebase" but it didnt work out foe me.

```
CT+aohc@MP1GYWQA MINGW64 /c/TCO/source/RAPMD.Web.Frontend (web_feature/TCORAPD-122389-1)
$ git pull origin dev
From https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/xxxx/_git/TCO-FGP-Rapmd
 * branch                  dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Comment: Do you have local changes in the same branch? What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: What did you try exactly? `git rebase origin/dev`? And what does "didn't work out for me" mean? Did you get any error or what happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106179/fatal-not-possible-to-fast-forward-aborting)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can follow the following steps:

- Run `git pull --rebase origin dev`
- if you face conflicts then you need to solve those conflicts and run

  - `git add <file_name>/ git add .`
  - `git rebase --continue`
- continue second step until you solve conflicts(remeber rebase compare changes commit wise)

  - Then run `git rebase --skip` if needed
- After you successfullly aplied rebase you need to force push the changes

  - Run `git push --force-with-lease origin dev` (safer way of force push) OR `git push -f origin dev`

FOR REFERENCE: https://gitexplorer.com/

Comment: be careful with rebasing, you might loose your work

Comment: @EugenSunic , Yes , You just need to solve the conflict properly. Then no code will be removed.

Answer (score 25):

Easiest way, This worked for me:

```
git fetch origin dev
git merge origin dev
```

Replace `dev` with `branch_name` you want to pull.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me

Comment: the 2 above commands are the same as `git pull origin`

Comment: Agree @EugenSunic

Comment: Finally something that works!

Answer (score 3):

Just add  --no-rebase to your pull command e.g.,
git pull origin  --no-rebase

This will take u to merge and a editor might open.
Write :WQ and enter

you should be able to successfully pull now.