# How to resolve a merge conflict

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

I got a merge conflict in multiple files when I tried a pull request in a github repo. While I know how to resolve merge conflicts in a normal case, my situation seems more convoluted.

**Master branch:**
The Master to which I am merging has no submodules. It had a dependency on libraries from another 3rd party repo, but instead of adding that as submodule, a snapshot was created originally.  Lets say dir2 is the snapshot of the 3rd party  dependency, the folder structure looked like this :  /dir1/ where  is not a submodule, but just a snapshot.

**mybranch issuing PR:**
Now in my branch "mybranch", I replaced the snapshot with the 3rd party submodule, but it still has the same structure, and same files :  /dir1/ where dir2 now is a submodule

When I issued a PR from "mybranch" I got merge conflicts in a few files in the main repo (no issues with ). To resolve them, I first issued "git pull origin master", when I get the following error:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
<dir2>/file1
<dir2>/file2
<dir2>/file3
...
..

Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
```

The issue clearly is because of the snapshot (in masteR) vs sub-module (in mybranch) with the same file names, but git does not detect it.

How do I resolve this situation ? thanks for any help

I am not a GIT expert, so didnt want to try something bold, and messing up the state of our repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72460052/15352279

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Create and checkout a new branch off from the latest master.
2. Checkout your changes from your original branch.
   git checkout myBranch --
3. Create a new PR.

It sidesteps merging with older master. And if you do it quickly hopefully master doesn't change too much :)

Not the best way to solve it (creating new PR is pretty ugly) but it is quite simple and an okay quick fix.

Comment: Thank you :) . that should work. and being a newbie, i am unable to upvote it sorry