# All merge conflicts cause an error, cannot be resolved

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Over the last few weeks, any time I get a merge conflict I get a fatal error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. checkout branch name
2. git pull origin master

At this point, my VScode would show the conflict(s) in the file and give me the opportunity of which to pick. This has happened for years..

But now, I get this error instead

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

VScode won't show me the conflict, there appears to be no way to resolve it except for deleting entire branch, creating a new branch from master, then rebuilding all my changes.

Comment: There are solutions that may apply in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106179/fatal-not-possible-to-fast-forward-aborting

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as those that are asking if (somehow) a `ff-only` option has been configured for `pull`.

Comment: Hi Topsail, thank you for posting that, I found that thread before posting this, I tried every item listed, not one helped

Comment: Do you get the same errors when you do a pull in a terminal (not with "vscode features")?

Comment: I tried both vscode and terminal, my default is to use terminal

Comment: what happens with `git fetch` followed by `git merge`? or `git pull --no-ff`. Have you inspected your local .git config (s) - there can be more than one!

Comment: git pull --no-ff, gets exact same error as git pull origin master

Comment: git fetch does nothing,  git merge "Already up to date"

Comment: Well sounds like you don't actually have a problem :) It seems you can check your pull configuration with this command `git config pull.ff` and if it responds `only` then you are configured for ff-only pulls.

Comment: After "git merge", "got fetch", if I do git pull --ff-only, now i get "Already up to date"

Comment: but bitbucket gives me a merge conflict error and wont let me merge

Comment: I double checked bitbucket again, still has conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steps to fix:

% vi ~/.gitconfig
in vi, type E

in edit screen, Comment out 2 lines

#[pull]

#ff only

Save, everything works

Answer (score 1):

The message:

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

means that you've told Git to use `--ff-only` for the merge that occurs as the second step of `git pull`<sup>1</sup> *and* that this merge *cannot* be done as a fast-forward.

There was a bug in Git 2.33 where [`--ff-only` misbehaved in certain cases](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fc3c0ad407008c2f71dd9ae1241d8b75f8ef886/Documentation/RelNotes/2.34.0.txt#L409-L414):

> ```
>  * "git pull --ff-only" and "git pull --rebase --ff-only" should make
>    it a no-op to attempt pulling from a remote that is behind us, but
>    instead the command errored out by saying it was impossible to
>    fast-forward, which may technically be true, but not a useful thing
>    to diagnose as an error.  This has been corrected.
>    (merge 361cb52383 jc/fix-pull-ff-only-when-already-up-to-date later to maint).
> ```

If you have this version of Git, you should upgrade to 2.34 or later.  [Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186710/all-merge-conflicts-cause-an-error-cannot-be-resolved#comment130982479_74186710) implies that you've hit this particular bug.

(Your comment about Bitbucket almost certainly involves something else entirely, and is a Bitbucket issue, not a Git one.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that `git pull` is a convenience short-cut that means:

1. run `git fetch`;
2. run a second Git command to do something with the commits obtained in step 1.

The default second command is `git merge` but you can choose `git rebase` instead.  The `--ff-only` option is an option to `git merge` and means nothing to `git rebase`, so `git pull` won't supply `--ff-only` to the second command if you choose `git rebase` (but it [*is* supposed to *stop* the rebase for that case](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fc3c0ad407008c2f71dd9ae1241d8b75f8ef886/Documentation/RelNotes/2.34.0.txt#L206-L209)).  Whether `git merge` supplies `--ff-only` to the second command if you choose `git merge` depends on how you configure `git pull` to operate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, we have a whole other team that manages this (upgrading git). I will reach out to them

Comment: Am I assume you mean on the server, my local version of git is 2.37.3

Comment: Wherever you got the `fatal` message. The only reason to get that message is when you've chosen `--ff-only` and there's no way to fast-forward, or to encounter the Git 2.33 bug; follow the link to see the details. You could get a *different* error message under various other tricky circumstances, though.