# Git fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a branch called 'a'. I am trying to pull from 'develop' to branch named 'a' using `git pull origin develop`, getting this error. How can I get rid of this?

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 14, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), 18.18 KiB | 846.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:
 * branch                develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   d8e8255db..b73523802  develop    -> origin/develop
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106179/fatal-not-possible-to-fast-forward-aborting

Comment: @IvanYuzafatau Is there an option to change that i get the changes just by git pull

Comment: Do two branches have the same parent branch or not?

Comment: You can try `git fetch origin develop` then `git merge origin/develop`