# Git not possible to fast-forward while pull.rebase is true

Tags: linux, git, config, rebase, pull

Basically the same situation as
[Error "Fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106179/error-fatal-not-possible-to-fast-forward-aborting) :

```
$ git pull
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

and its answer solved the problem:

```
$ git pull --rebase
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

However, the question is on the next line:

> To set this option globally, use git config --global pull.rebase true

I've already done that, both globally and locally:

```
$ git config --global pull.rebase
true

$ git config pull.rebase
true
```

But why I still need the `--rebase` when doing `git pull`?

There is also [one answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280513/2125837) saying to turn `rebase = false`, which I totally don't understand. Here is my sistuation:

```
$ grep -1 rebase ~/.gitconfig
[pull]
        rebase = true
        ff = only
```

How not to use the `--rebase` when doing `git pull`?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to pull with a fast-forward-merge and git isn't letting you or do you want git to do a rebase when pulling?

Comment: I want to config git to do a rebase by default when pulling, based on your question @vatbub, as I don't know if there are other options exist or not, or whether what you asked have to be mutually exclusive. What's in my ~/.gitconfig file is what accumulated throughout the years, from various suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> But why I still need the `--rebase` when doing `git pull`?

You should not.
But I [usually combine that setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309) with `git config --global rebase.autoStash true`

That way, the working tree is clear, ready for the rebase.

Make sure you have a recent enough Git for that (2.27+ for rebase+autoStash).

Note: the [`pull.ff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullff) is not needed in that case, since you are rebasing on `pull`.

```
git config --global --unset pull.ff
```

Comment: I do have `git config --global rebase.autoStash true` and I did _have to_ use --rebase when doing git pull. Do you have `ff = only` in you `~/.gitconfig` file?

Comment: @xpt I do not, that would be incompatible with the rebase option and is needed only when you do a regular pull with merge. I have edited the answer accordingly.