# How to make git merge's default --no-ff only for remotes?

Tags: git, merge

The general answer is given here: [How do I make git merge's default be --no-ff --no-commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519007/how-do-i-make-git-merges-default-be-no-ff-no-commit)

But how to enforce this *only for remote branches* ? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, or at least, not as far as I know; and see caveats below: I suspect what you want to do has sufficiently limited usefulness that you may be going about it the wrong way.  (See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))

(I also think [VonC's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/1256452) is worth reading before attempting to use this answer.)

If you do your merges "manually" you can always write your own script to do it.  (This means avoiding `git pull` in favor of `git fetch` for instance: run `git fetch`, then your `do-merge` script, whatever you call it.)

So: how can you write a script that mimics `git merge`?  This depends on how thorough you want to be, of course.  You can use `git rev-parse --parseopt` to parse arguments for you (for instance, see the `git-rebase` script plus the `git-sh-setup` script, both in the `git-core` directory, often `/usr/libexec` or `/usr/local/libexec`, although installations vary).

You must also decide whether to use `merge.defaultToUpstream` if there are no *`commit`* arguments, and how thorough you want to be about detecting in-progress merges, modified work directories before a merge starts, and so on.

In any case, let's say you've gotten to the point in the script where you're ready to run the "real" `git merge` command, and you want to add `--no-ff --no-commit` if and only if (1) the arguments to the script do not override this, and (2) a "commit" to be merged, whether given directly or implied by `merge.defaultToUpstream`, names a "remote branch".  How do you decide that the commit *is* a "remote branch"?

The simplest test is to run `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` on it.  If the resulting name starts with `refs/remotes/`, the name is symbolic and names a remote branch:

```
name_is_remote_branch() {
    local full

    full=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $1)
    case $full in
    refs/remotes/*) return 0;;
    *) return 1;;
    esac
}
```

The above shell function can be used as, e.g.:

```
if name_is_remote_branch origin/master; then
    echo seems to work
else
    echo oops
fi
```

or (shorter, and still just for demonstration):

```
name_is_remote_branch master || echo ok # master should not be "remote branch"
```

(In other words, just like any "real command", the function returns 0 for success/true, and nonzero for "failure"/false, so `boolean_test && if_true` and `boolean_test || if_false` are useable shorthand.)

Now you can use the little shell function to test a symbolic reference given to your merge script, provided of course that condition (1) ("arguments to script do not override") is also met.

## Caveats

1. Merges actually work by commit IDs, which are permanent; but your automatic control knob is based on commit *name*, which is changeable.

   What happens if we apply this test to a raw SHA-1 ID?

   ```
   $ git log -1 --decorate --oneline
   676699a (origin/master, master) commit subject here
   ```

   If I am on some other branch and run `do-merge 676699a`, what do you *want* to happen?  Note that this particular commit-ID has two labels, `origin/master` (a remote branch) and `master` (a local branch).  I've given neither *label* as argument, but I've asked to merge that particular *commit*.

   The function as written says that this is *not* a remote branch.  (In particular, `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` outputs nothing and exits 0, indicating success; the `case` then compares the empty string against the two glob patterns and only matches the second.)

   If you want something else to happen, you'll need more actions.  You can add a case pattern for the empty string, which is the "symbolic full name" you get back for any valid SHA-1 that is not a symbolic name.  (This includes things that are not even commits, nor resolvable to commits, too.)  You can then do whatever you want for these cases, but you need to figure out what it is you want.

   Note that the `git-sh-setup` script has a function, `peel_commitish`, that can help resolve a revision specifier to a commit.  (As with all these cases it winds up using `git rev-parse`, this time with the special `^0` suffix, which means the same as `^{commit}`.)
2. What about octopus merges?

   For instance, what does it mean if I am on branch `B` and ask to merge (by name) both branches `feature1` and `origin/feature2`?  Am I merging a remote branch or a local one, in terms of whether to use `--no-ff --no-commit` by default?