# Git merge without fast forward by default

Tags: git, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make fast forwarding be off by default in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git)

Is there any way to globally make git not do a fast forward merge by default? I keep forgetting to add --no-ff when I finish a feature and merge my feature branch back into mainline.

Comment: See [Can I make fast forwarding be off by default in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes. set merge.ff with git config. ( http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html )

```
git config merge.ff false
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Git on the command line, you should be using aliases for common commands/options. They're the difference between making Git agonizing or useful:

```
alias gm="git merge --no-ff"
```

Comment: This is just workaround. There is no effect if some 3'd party application try to merge.

Comment: But it has the advantage of not affecting git pull