# Github merge --no-ff with Github for Mac app

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I have a requirement in my project to merge my branch to Master using a "--no-ff" merge.
I would like to use the github for mac app, which doesn't seem to have advanced options for merging.
How would I set up this type of merge as the default for my project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make fast forwarding be off by default in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git)

Comment: not a duplicate, the OP is asking how to do `--no-ff` via github for mac. Your link only shows the `--no-ff` option, which the OP has clearly assimilated

Comment: Do you ***have to use GitHub for Mac***? This is a trivial thing to do via the command line, it's simply `git merge --no-ff <branch>`.

Comment: I would give you the same advice as @Cupcake, using the Terminal is simple and you've total control on your repository