# how to add option ' git merge --no-ff ' in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Can't find for a long period of time how to add this option in TortoiseGit

[What is the difference between `git merge` and `git merge --no-ff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)

Can anyone explain how do I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with TortoiseGit but rather with Git itself.

Go to the repository's directory in your shell and execute a command

```
git config --add --local merge.ff true
```

to force only fast-forward merges for that particular repository.

Note that TortoiseGit does not include any Git *substitute,* — instead, it piggybacks on [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io) installation, so if you have TortoiseGit installed you have Git for Windows installed as well.

Comment: To specify `--no-ff` you should put `false` at the end. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810687/2796922](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810687/2796922)

Answer (score 8):

See this attached image as the answer.

[image: TortoiseGit merge --no-ff]

Comment: Can anyone tell how can it be saved to be default?

Comment: probably can not - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148254/how-can-i-set-merge-no-fast-forward-as-the-default-in-tortoisegit