# How can I set merge "No Fast Forward" as the default in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I don't use fast-forward merges in my workflow. I note that in git itself, one can include this in their .gitconfig to get fast forwarding off by default:

```
[merge]
    ff = false
```

TortoiseGit doesn't seem to do anything with this, though. When I go to merge, the "No Fast Forward" checkbox is still unticked. When I carry out the merge, I see it still invokes the command `git.exe merge Branch_test`, without the `--no-ff` switch.

How do I get it to default off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha!

Setting

```
[merge]
    ff = false
```

in the config file *does* prevent fast forwarding when merging using TortoiseGit, because that changes the behaviour of `git.exe` itself.

With that option added, the "No Fast Forward" checkbox on the merge dialogue **will not do anything!** Instead, all merges will be "no fast forward" merges.

It's a bit clumsy, because it means I don't have the option in the TortoiseGit dialogue to override that default (ie, to use the `--ff` switch on the merge command). Still, it does approximately what I need.