# Git commits appear in all branches not just the ones I specify

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github, merge

This may be a fairly simple problem with how I'm using git or how I'm integrating it with Visual Studio 2012. I have (or thought I had) two major branches: master and develop.

I rarely touch the master branch, I mostly make commits to the develop branch and when I reach a milestone I merge the develop branch with the master branch. If I'm introducing a new feature, I make a new branch feat/SomeFeature off from the develop branch. When that feature is done, I merge that with the develop branch and then merge that with the master branch.

Switching branches does exactly what I expect it to do, I see the old untouched versions of the code. However, when I open the repo in a branch visualisation program it appears that all my commits are all along one branch:

[image]

I was expecting to see loops and merges, like in this screenshot:
[image]

Why do my branches appear different? Why do all my commits appear along one branch?

Comment: Can you try one of the built-in visualization tools and see if it agrees with what you see with Git Extensions? `gitk --all` or `git log --all --graph --decorate` should work from a console (assuming you've got `git` in your path).

Comment: I ran git log --all --graph --decorate and it does seem to agree with what Git Extensions displays. http://i.imgur.com/bYwZxW1.png 
I wasn't doubting Git Extensions, I think I must be doing something wrong in my branches but I don't understand what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's going on

It's hard to know exactly what's going on without more information, but you are probably getting [*fast-forward merges*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast-forward_merge). Basically, if Git can flatten a merge it defaults to doing so. Your workflow of working primarily in `develop` and merging that repeatedly into `master` predisposes you to fast-forward merges.

(Note that there is nothing inherently *wrong* with fast-forward merging. Some developers love this flow and go out of their way to only use this merge strategy by `rebase`ing their work before merging. Other developers, myself included, like to see "merge bubbles" for feature merges.)

As an example, consider the following commit graph:

```
[master]   A---B---C
                    \
[develop]            D---E---F
```

`master` contains commits `A`, `B` and `C`. `develop` contains commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`.

At this  point, if you merge `develop` into `master` Git will default to a fast-forward merge, resulting in

```
[master] [develop] A---B---C---D---E---F
```

This happens because the merge would logically result in the same commits existing in both trees: You are merging commits `D`, `E` and `F` onto a branch that already contains `A`, `B` and `C`.

If the previous graph looked different, for example

```
[master]   A---B---C---G
                    \
[develop]            D---E---F
```

something different would happen. You would end up with something like this:

```
[master]   A---B---C---G-------H
                    \         /
[develop]            D---E---F
```

In this case you get a new commit H, which is called a *merge commit*.

### Keeping merge bubbles

You can force the latter behaviour using the `--no-ff` flag to `git merge`. (There is also a `--ff-only` flag to force the opposite behaviour.) From the first example a `git checkout master && git merge --no-ff develop` would result in something like this

```
[master]   A---B---C-----------G
                    \         /
[develop]            D---E---F
```

Note the new merge commit `G`.

### Visual Studio

This is all from the perspective of Git on the command-line, but I note that you are using Visual Studio. I am not sure how to trigger the `--no-ff` option to merge from VS, assuming you are performing your merges from that tool. Sadly, many graphical Git clients hide very useful options like this flag.

Comment: I think this might explain it! Is this a flag I can set in the git config file? I think it could be something I could add to 
[merge]
ff = false ?

Comment: Yes, this was precisely when the issue! When I use Git Extensions to make the commits and merges and explicitly tell it to not use fast-forward merges, it displays the loops that I was anticipating. Thank you!

Comment: @mortenalbring, glad it helped. [You can make `--no-ff` the default *per branch*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git). Edit: [It looks like there is now a sorta-kinda-default way to set this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810687/354577).