# Enforce recursive merge in master i.e. it should create a merge commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure in such a way that it does a recursive merge always when merging into master (throughout the team) so that I can find the base commit (of the merge commit) to know the repository state before merge?

Answer (score 1):

That would be a `git merge --no-ff`, in order to be sure to avoid a [fast-forward merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/6309) and always generate a merge commit.

As mentioned in "[Can I make fast forwarding be off by default in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500446/6309)", you can attach that only to the master branch

```
git config branch.master.mergeoptions  "--no-ff"
```

Comment: Also, there is `branch.master.mergeoptions` in git config files (would need to be set for all users doing such merges).

Comment: @torek yep, I was researching that as you were writing your comment ;)

Comment: will this apply to everyone in the team if executed on the remote repo?

Comment: Actually I was looking for some way to enforce it on everyone in the team.

Comment: @iSid no, this would apply only to merges done directly on the rmeote repo itself. Everyone in the team is working on their *clone* of that remote repo: they need to set that config individually. Configs in Git never propagate between repos.