# How do I set "--no-ff" option auto-enabled in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, fast-forward

Every time when I merge I have to set this option checked manually.

[image]

Is there any opportunity to set this flag on for the project only one time?

I already set my config preferences with command line to use `--no-ff` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git)), but it didn't affect IDEA's UI anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make fast forwarding be off by default in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500296/can-i-make-fast-forwarding-be-off-by-default-in-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to set this by default.
And this UI option does not respect the git config at the moment.

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86425