# Is there a way to set default config for a specific branch to --no-ff

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

To be clear, I want to be able to set branchA to do **fast forward merge** by default and branch B to do `--no-ff` merge by default.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: No, I know how to set no-ff globally or for the entire repo.  I'm asking about doing it only for a specific branch.

Comment: [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500446) says how to do it for a specific branch.